# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while returning returning address of local variable

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a C program in ubuntu : A function returns address of local variable.

Like below :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *function();
int main(){
    int *j;
    j=function();
    printf("i value : %d",*j);
    return 0;
}

int *function(){
    int i=10;
    printf("In function : %u",&i);
    return (&i);
}
```

I am getting Segmentation fault (core dumped). I saw some of the threads from 
[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)
It says Segmentation fault is a specific kind of error caused by accessing memory that “does not belong to you.
But in my case, how can we say that the "Memory Not Belonging to Me".

Please help me for deep understanding.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an UB. The memory relative to automatic variables is formally invalid after the scope in which they are declared is finished. However the segmentation fault is generated by OS that can enforce, as seems in your case, a strong protection of stack allocated memory.

Comment: Its not matter of static. static has its own importance. For my case I want to use  automatic storage only.

Comment: @xing is right. Adding `static` to your `int i` will do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant return address of *automatic storage variable* which is on stack just in `function`'s body, becouse it got out of scope (ended its lifetime) -> ([undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). You need to dynamically allocate space on heap for the variable if you want to return it from function.

```
int * i = malloc (sizeof(int));
// Check if i != NULL
if (i == NULL) { perror("malloc failure"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
return i;
```

Then you can assign the value referenced by the pointer `i`:

```
*i = 34;
```

Dont forget to free memory in main

```
    free(i);
```

Comment: No need to check `j` for `NULL`. `free()` accepts a null-pointer.

Comment: Seems its like  int *j;
        printf("%d",*j);